# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto' ubuntu 18 python 3.6.7

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, pycrypto

I have a python version 3.6.7 installed in ubuntu 18 and I'm trying to run code that has 'import crypto' in it. whenever I run the code the following error occurs:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

[image]

I've tried to install Crypto and Pcrypto and they are successfully installed but the above error still occurs.

Can you guys please help me, I'm googling this error for days and no solution?

Comment: Where are you running the python code, from command line, text editor... Make sure you are running python 3.6 version.  You may be running python's 2.7 version

Comment: I'm running the code from python shell and I'm sure the version is 3.6. Do you need a screen shot for my machine?

Comment: Try to run pip3 install ... Your pip uninstall is on python 2.7. See the first line on the right screenshot

Comment: oh yeah, I didn't notice. I will try

Comment: It worked. I installed pip3 and use the following command: pip3 install crypto and the code is running perfectly.